# Vanilla Javascript with jQuery Like Syntax

Tags: javascript

I know that it is possible to replace jQuery with vanilla JavaScript.  For example, we can replace `$('.some-class')` with `document.querySelector('.some-class')`.

All in all that is great.  The only thing I don't like is how verbose the vanilla JavaScript syntax is.  `document.querySelctor` vs `$`.

I am wondering if it is possible with vanilla JavaScript to get a jQuery like syntax.  It doesn't have to be a dollar sign.  Perhaps `qs('.some-class')` - or something similar.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Alias it, eg use `const qs = document.querySelector`  If you’re serving gzipped and minified JS this should be the least of your worries tbh. You also need to realize that JQuery objects have methods that allow implicit iteration, e.g. `$(selector).text(...)`. You can’t do it with `qs(selector).innerText = ...` for example. All in all I think this is a rather meaningless venture because you will then end up writing your own selector library and reinventing the wheel.

Comment: jQuery is built with and *needs* vanilla javascript to work at all so...yes.

Comment: @moche, my answer is comprehensive and should explain the how and the why. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Any questions @moshe? My answer below should show some common ways of achieving it, but with the caveat that we do start to re-invent the wheel. If my answer solved your problem, consider up-voting and marking as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as the comments say, you can definitely do this with modern [js](/questions/tagged/js)

Let's see some different ways we could achieve something similar to [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) with some examples:

```js
const qs = (query, att, val) => {
    const multiple = document.querySelectorAll(query);
    const setAtt = (child,index) => {
      try {
        child[att] = val;
      } catch(e1){
          try{
            child.setAttribute(att, val);
          } catch(e2){
            console.log('error', e1, e2);
          }
      }
    };    
    //if its only 1 element it only runs once
    multiple.forEach(setAtt);
}

qs('.single', 'innerText', 'Example');
qs('.multiple', 'innerText', 'Example2');
qs('.multiple', 'style', 'height: 25px; background-color: blue;');
```

```css
div.single, div.multiple {
  height: 50px;
  clear: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="single"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
```

But as the comments also say, if you end up wanting 1-for-1 feature-for-feature coverage with respect to JQuery, you will end up just reinventing the wheel.

And to build it the same so that you can chain methods requires a different approach (always returning an object that can then access the methods again etc.)

And to be clear, vanilla JS can now do most things really nicely in my opinion.

Here is the same example in vanilla JS:

```js
const qs = (query) => document.querySelectorAll(query);

qs('.single').forEach(child => child.innerText = 'Example');
qs('.multiple').forEach(child => child.innerText = 'Example2');
qs('.multiple').forEach(child => child.setAttribute('style','height: 25px; background-color: blue;'));
```

```css
div.single, div.multiple {
  height: 50px;
  clear: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="single"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
```

**I was curious how we would create an object/function that allows method chaining like JQuery so I set out to create it:**

```js
const qs = (query) => {
    const returnObj = {
      multiple: document.querySelectorAll(query),
      setAtt: function(att, val) {
        return function(child,index){
          try {
            child[att] = val;
          } catch(e1){
              try{
                child.setAttribute(att, val);
              } catch(e2){
                console.log('error', e1, e2);
              }
          }
        }
      },
      //if its only 1 element it only runs once    
      set innerText(val) {this.multiple.forEach(this.setAtt('innerText',val) ) },
      set style(val) {this.multiple.forEach(this.setAtt('style',val) ) }
    }
    return returnObj;
}

qs('.single').innerText = 'Example';
qs('.multiple').innerText = 'Example2';
qs('.multiple').style = 'height: 25px; background-color: blue;';

//https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp
```

```css
div.single, div.multiple {
  height: 50px;
  clear: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="single"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
```

Or, we could do it without setters and the API could look like this (probably closer to JQuery):

```js
const qs = (query) => {
    const returnObj = {
      multiple: document.querySelectorAll(query),
      setAtt: function(att, val) {
        return function(child,index){
          try {
            child[att] = val;
          } catch(e1){
              try{
                child.setAttribute(att, val);
              } catch(e2){
                console.log('error', e1, e2);
              }
          }
        }
      },
      getAtt: function(att) {
        return function(child,index){
          if (child[att]) {
            return child[att];
          } else{
              try{
                return child.getAttribute(att);
              } catch(e2){
                console.log('error', e2);
                return false;
              }
          }
        }
      },
      _DOM_methods: function(att, val){        
        if (val){  
          this.multiple.forEach(this.setAtt(att,val) )
          return this;
        } else{
          const returnArr = [...this.multiple].map(this.getAtt(att) )
          if (returnArr.length == 1){
            return returnArr[0];
          } else{
            return returnArr;
          }   
        } 
      },
      //if its only 1 element it only runs once
      //if val is not supplied it returns the current val
      innerText: function(val) {
        return this._DOM_methods('innerText', val);
      },
      style: function(val) {
         return this._DOM_methods('style', val);
      }
    }
    return returnObj;
}

qs('.single').innerText('Example');
qs('.multiple')
  .innerText('Example2')
  .style('height: 25px; background-color: blue;');

console.log(qs('.single').innerText());
console.log(qs('.multiple').innerText());
```

```css
div.single, div.multiple {
  height: 50px;
  clear: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="single"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
<div class="multiple"></div>
```

See how you can chain methods here and also recieve back current values:

```
qs('.single').innerText('Example');
qs('.multiple')
  .innerText('Example2')
  .style('height: 25px; background-color: blue;');

console.log(qs('.single').innerText());
console.log(qs('.multiple').innerText());
```

Comment: Very interesting experiment, Alex. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusParsons glad you found it interesting